# API for getting plugin core compatibility?

Tags: plugins

I’m looking for a way to determine which version of Wordpress a plugin has been tested to work with. Only way I’ve found is by looking at the plugin’s homepage. I can scrape that but I’m wondering if there is an API or some other better way to get this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you what you are looking for:

[Wordpress.org API for Plugins](https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/%7Bslug%7D)

Here's the full documentation:

[Wordpress.org API Doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress.org_API)